# Variable that points to one Enum or either another Enum?

Tags: vb.net, enums

I have a .NET project, in which an Excel is uploaded and converted row by row into objects. This works fine.

I have defined an enum to create a mapping between the columns in the Excel file and the index of their column, which I need to get the value from the column

as so:

```
 Public Enum ColumnIndexEnum
       FirstName = 1
       LastName = 2
       Address = 3
       ...
 End Enum
```

This is used like this: (pseudo-code)

```
   Dim row = 1
   WorkSheet.GetValue(ColumnIndexEnum.FirstName, row)
```

I have used the enum in the past to enter new columns. I could just edit the Enum by entering a new entry and wouldn't have to change any of the code that reads the specific columns

Now I have to make a change in which some columns will disappear in some cases, but will return in other cases. In other words: sometimes the column FirstName will be the first Column (index 1), and at other times, it will be the second column.

And I am at a loss how to best approach this. I was thinking of creating a second Enum and switching the Enum I use, but can't find out any details on how I would create a variable that either points to one Enum, or to another.

Does anyone have any ideas on this? I use VB.NET for this project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this in a helper function like this:

```
Public Enum ColumnIndexEnum
   FirstName = 1
   LastName = 2
   Address = 3
   ...
 End Enum

Public Enum ColumnType
   FirstType = 1
   SecondType = 2
   ...
 End Enum

Public Function GetColumn(ByVal col As ColumnIndexEnum, ByVal colType As ColumnType) As Integer
    Select Case col
        Case ColumnIndexEnum.FirstName
            If colType = ColumnType.FirstType Then
                Return 1
            ElseIf colType = ColumnType.SecondType Then
                Return 2
            End If
        Case ColumnIndexEnum.SecondName
            If colType = ColumnType.FirstType Then
                Return 2
            ElseIf colType = ColumnType.SecondType Then
                Return 3
            End If
        ...
    End Select
End Function
```

Then you can use it as such:

```
Dim row = 1
WorkSheet.GetValue(GetColumn(ColumnIndexEnum.FirstName,ColumnType.FirstType), row)
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, so thank you! Just one small thing though. In the GetColumn-method, I allowed it to take a string, which is the name of the column (not the title, just the name I use in the back-end). It tries to parse this to the correct enum depending on the time using Enum.TryParse. So my solution was a little shorter than yours.

But your suggestion got me on the right track, so thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a "variable that either points to one enum or another". Firstly, because it's a typed language, and secondly because it's not a reference type (which can be pointed to). You can simply store the column index by casting the enum to an integer (or whatever the backing type of the enum is). At the end of the day, that's all the enum is doing for you really, giving you an alias for some numeric value, and casting allows you to get that underlying value.

Answer (score 1):

This is more a structural problem since you only use enums to have a readable name for your integer values.

Lets say the existing excel format is as you put it:

```
Public Enum ColumnIndexEnum
   FirstName = 1
   LastName = 2
   Address = 3
   ...
End Enum
```

and now you have another excel format where firstname is column 2 and Title is column 1 like:

```
Public Enum ColumnIndexEnum2
   Title = 1
   FirstName = 2
   LastName = 3
   Address = 4
   ...
End Enum
```

So yes, you can just create new enums as you like and use them. However, I personally have used EPPlus or CSVReader nuget packages myself since i do not have to rely on a specific column order and i can read the value given the name of the column. Its another story if you do not have column names.

Comment: I use EPPlus as well. Can I read a column by it's name? I did not know this! Do you happen to know how? Most examples use the index integer.

Comment: Yes, there is another post on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39958798/epplus-find-column-using-column-name

Answer (score 0):

Starting here

```
Public Enum ColumnIndexEnum
    FirstName = 1
    LastName = 2
    Address = 3
End Enum

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim row = 1
    WorkSheet.GetValue(ColumnIndexEnum.FirstName, row)
End Sub
```

Step1- change name of enum. (use red underscore to change all names)

```
Public Enum ColumnIndexGetter
    FirstName = 1
    LastName = 2
    Address = 3
End Enum

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim row = 1
    WorkSheet.GetValue(ColumnIndexGetter.FirstName, row)
End Sub
```

Step2 - get rid of enum

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim row = 1
    WorkSheet.GetValue(ColumnIndexGetter.FirstName, row)
End Sub
```

Step3 - define new variable

```
Private ColumnIndexGetter As Cases
```

and the class for Cases.  You'll need to modify this to fit the actual situation, hopefully you get the idea.

```
Public Class Cases
    Private Enum ColumnIndexCase1
        FirstName = 1
        LastName = 2
        Address = 3
    End Enum

    Private Enum ColumnIndexCase2
        FirstName = 2
        LastName = 3
        Address = 7
    End Enum

    Private _whCase As Integer
    Public Sub New(WhichCase As Integer)
        Me._whCase = WhichCase
    End Sub

    Public Function FirstName() As Integer
        Dim rv As Integer = 0
        Select Case Me._whCase
            Case 1
                rv = ColumnIndexCase1.FirstName

            Case 2
                rv = ColumnIndexCase2.FirstName

        End Select
        Return rv
    End Function

    Public Function LastName() As Integer
        Dim rv As Integer = 0
        Select Case Me._whCase
            Case 1
                rv = ColumnIndexCase1.LastName

            Case 2
                rv = ColumnIndexCase2.LastName

        End Select
        Return rv
    End Function

    Public Function Address() As Integer
        Dim rv As Integer = 0
        Select Case Me._whCase
            Case 1
                rv = ColumnIndexCase1.Address

            Case 2
                rv = ColumnIndexCase2.Address

        End Select
        Return rv
    End Function
End Class
```

finally, before using ColumnIndexGetter you'll need

```
    ColumnIndexGetter = New Cases(1)
    'or
    ColumnIndexGetter = New Cases(2)
```

and then the code will look like

```
Private ColumnIndexGetter As Cases
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    ColumnIndexGetter = New Cases(1)
    'or
    ColumnIndexGetter = New Cases(2)

    Dim row = 1
    WorkSheet.GetValue(ColumnIndexGetter.FirstName, row)
End Sub
```

The actual location of the initialization of ColumnIndexGetter will probably be where you know which case you are dealing with.